# How to get correct (or no document) sources in when answering chat application using Langchain's ConversationalRetrievalQAChain?

Tags: typescript, langchain, large-language-model

```
import { OpenAI } from 'langchain/llms/openai'
import { ConversationalRetrievalQAChain } from 'langchain/chains'
import { Chroma } from 'langchain/vectorstores/chroma'
import { BufferMemory } from 'langchain/memory'

const makeChain = (vectorstore: Chroma) => {
  const model = new OpenAI({
    temperature: 0, // increase temepreature to get more creative answers
    modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo', // change this to gpt-4 if you have access
  })

  const questionModel = new OpenAI({})

  const chain = ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(
    model,
    vectorstore.asRetriever(),
    {
      returnSourceDocuments: true,
      memory: new BufferMemory({
        humanPrefix:
          'I want you to act as a document that I am having a conversation with. You will provide me with answers from the given info. If the answer is not included, search for an answer and return it. Never break character.',
        memoryKey: 'chat_history',
        inputKey: 'question', // The key for the input to the chain
        outputKey: 'text', // The key for the final conversational output of the chain
        returnMessages: true, // If using with a chat model
      }),
      questionGeneratorChainOptions: {
        llm: questionModel,
      },
    },
  )
  return chain
}

export default makeChain
```

**EXPLANATION**

I am currently working on a project where i have implemented the ConversationalRetrievalQAChain, as the above code snippet. I have set the option "returhSourceDocuments" set to true. the system is working fine when i ask question related to the document that i fed, but when i give a generic questions like "Who is buddha?" and greetings like "hi", "hello", "hey" etc. it returns unrelated source documents that don't align with my question. It seems like the vector store is always returning a source documents, irrespective of the match query.

Is there any way to tackle this problem ? Is there any way to mitigate this issue?

I have researched on Contextual compression and EmbeddingsFilter but i failed to mitigate it. Is there any way provided by LangChain to mitigate it ?